# Calling instance method with class

Tags: java, instance-variables

I found the following code online:

```
class TestA
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 A a1 = new A();
 A a2 = new A(5);
 a2.setValue(10);
 System.out.println(a1.getValue() + " " +a2.getValue() + " " + A.getChanges());
 }
}
```

I understand the `a1.getValue` and `a2.getValue` because they are object references calling to instance methods. And if I follow the `TestA` methods below, I get the correct first two answers "0 10". But I don't understand `A.getChanges()`, because it's the class itself calling to the instance methods. Why does it do this? Also, if I follow the `changes` variable, I think that this should return 2, but when I tested it in Java, I'm getting a return of "0 10 3". Can anyone explain this?

And a class called `A`:

```
class A
 {
 private static int changes = 0;
 private int value;
  public A() {
   this(0);
  }
  public A(int value) {
   setValue(value);
  }
  public int getValue() {
   return value;
  }
  public void setValue(int value) {
   this.value = value;
   changes++;
  }
  public static int getChanges() {
   return changes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Static methods are class methods, not instance methods.

Comment: There are a total of three calls to `setValue`, two through the constructors and one explicit. Each call increments the static field `changes`, so its final value is 3.

Comment: Right! Thank you both! I don't have much practice with this. So, @PatriciaShanahan, so do I treat objects like arrays in the sense where I always take the newest value assigned, in this case 10?